# How to turn of pop up authentication in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I am using SSRS 2019 for my reports to View. But when I am trying to access my reports is asks for username and password by a pop up window and In here I have to use my admin username and password
[Here is the pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GN4ea.png)

If I want to make my admin username and password default what can I do?
Can I send username and password with url or can I set it up anywhere in my web.config or rsreportserver.config? I don't want to see this popup when I am accessing my 'ReportServer' url.

Comment: Its configured for windows authentication. If you are running this correct within a domain you won't get asked for this.

Comment: @DaleK I have tried <authentication mode="Windows" />, <authentication mode="Forms" />, <authentication mode="None" /> nothing worked. Also <AuthenticationTypes>
   <RSWindowsNTLM/>
   <RSWindowsNegotiate/>
  </AuthenticationTypes>

Comment: Okay I solved my Issue by using my URL by this 'http:userLogin:userPassword@myDomain.com/ReportServer'

Comment: Are you actually using the server name / FQDN?  If I connect to my SSRS server using the IP address, then I get prompted for credentials, but if I use the FQDN it authenticates without prompting.  Also, which browser/s are encountering the prompting?

Comment: @ZihanHossain that seems a bit insecure

Comment: I agree with DaleK, that's very unsecure. Have you actually granted access to the reports for the domain users via the Web Portal? If you have done that then you should be OK unless your datasource uses the users credentials in which case they would need database access to. Alternatively, used fixed SQL credentials in the datasource then oyu only need to grant access to the reports and/or report folders.#